# Show an alert that looks like SKStoreReviewController

Tags: ios, app-store, skstorereviewcontroller

How can I show an alert thats similar to SKStoreReviewController?

I like how it looks and I want to use a similar UI on my app.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Do you want the look or the functionality, or both?

Comment: I want the look with custom functionality.

Comment: I looked for something built-in a while ago and never came up with anything, ended up making my own alert UIViewController http://imgur.com/a/5lnn3 There is a container around all the other views with a  corner radius.

Comment: Looks good for that use case. But I want one with the stars too.

Comment: Adding stars should be fairly trivial if you have a custom alert view all wired up. Get a star empty and filled graphic, a little logic and bam. I'll see if theres anything in my implementation that could be useful to put as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new view controller

```
let vc = UIViewController()
vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 250,height: 300)
```

Create everything you want on your view, for example a picker view

```
let pickerView = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 300))
pickerView.delegate = self
pickerView.dataSource = self
```

Then add it to the view controller

```
vc.view.addSubview(pickerView)
```

With that you can create an alert view and set the view controller for the key contentViewController

```
let customAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
customAlert.setValue(vc, forKey: "contentViewController")

let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) {
    UIAlertAction in

        // what should happen when you click ok

    }


customAlert.addAction(okAction)
customAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Abort", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
self.present(customAlert, animated: true)
```

Instead of adding a picker to the vc, you can also build the stuff you need for the review (Images, Labels, Slider, etc.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: What about the stars?

Comment: Come on, you have over 16.000 rep :) The stars are just a line of buttons.

Comment: I was hoping for something I could just copy paste :'(